# How do I make fit work in logistic regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to fit data using logistic regression, but I am getting a value error.

I am working with iris dataset from sklearn:

```
# The data is in iris["data"] and target in iris["target"]
# For this section, we will work with a single feature 'petal width'
# which is the last (fourth) feature in iris["data"]
# We will assign class y=1 if the target's value is 2 and 0 otherwise

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()

# petal width
X = np.array([len(iris["data"]),1]).reshape(-1,1)
# 1 if Iris virginica, else 0
y = []
for x in iris["target"]:
    if x == 2.0:
        y.append(1)
    else:
        y.append(0)
y = np.array(y)

# Import the LogisticRegression class from scikit learn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Initialize the LogisticRegression class, use lbfgs solver and random state of 42
log_reg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', random_state=42)

# Fit the data
log_reg.fit(X, y)
```

This is where I reach

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 150]
```

Unsure whether it is my x or y that is being set up incorrectly?

Comment: can you print out the shapes of x and y after `y = np.array(y)` and add it into your question? Usully that error has to do with incorrect dimensions in my experience

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the wrong reshaping of `X` you are attempting here:

```
X = np.array([len(iris["data"]),1]).reshape(-1,1)
```

which results in a

```
X.shape
# (2,1)
```

hence the inconsistent number of samples, since

```
y.shape
# (150,)
```

This reshaping is wrong; since, as it seems from the comments in your code, you want only the 4th feature (petal width), you should change it to:

```
X = iris['data'][:,3].reshape(-1,1)
```

which gives indeed the correct shape:

```
X.shape
# (150, 1)
```

and you model will be fitted without issues (tested).